# Exclusion of all rows possible via outer join?

Tags: mysql

I'll start off with the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomersActions (
   `caID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
   `cusID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `caTimestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
CREATE TABLE `Assignments` (
    `asgID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    `cusID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `asgAssigned` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `astID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE `AssignmentStatuses` (
   `astID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
   `astStatus` varchar(255) DEFAULT ''
)
```

My original query is:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
     ca.cusID
  FROM
     CustomersActions ca
  WHERE      
     NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
           TRUE
        FROM
           Assignments asg
           NATURAL JOIN AssignmentStatuses
        WHERE
           asg.cusID = ca.cusID
           AND (
              DATE_ADD(asgAssigned, INTERVAL 6 DAY) > NOW()
              OR astStatus IN('Not contacted', 'Follow-up')
           )
     )
```

What this does is select all `cusID` entries from CustomersActions if said Customer does not have a row in `Assignments` that is in "Not contacted" or "Follow-up" (for any date range) OR has an assignment of *any* status from less than six days ago.

I tried writing the same query using `LEFT JOIN` to exclude from `Assignments` like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ca.cusID
FROM
    CustomersActions ca
    LEFT JOIN (
       Assignments asg
       NATURAL JOIN AssignmentStatuses
    ) ON (ca.cusID = asg.cusID)
WHERE
    asgID IS NULL
    OR DATE_ADD(asgAssigned, INTERVAL 6 DAY) < NOW()
    OR astStatus IN('Not contacted', 'Follow-up')
```

The problem is that it's possible for a customer to have multiple entries in `Assignments` so a `cusID` can be selected even if they have an existing row that should force them to be excluded.  This makes sense to me, and the `NOT EXISTS` solves this problem.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to perform a single query that has the same effect as the query when using `NOT EXISTS`.  That is, a customer should be excluded if they have any rows that satisfy the exclusion condition, not only if *all* of their rows satisfy the exclusion condition (or if they have none).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `NOT IN` clause, like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ca.cusID
FROM
 CustomersActions ca
WHERE cusID    
 NOT IN (
    SELECT
       cusID
    FROM
       Assignments asg
       INNER JOIN AssignmentStatuses ast
       ON asg.astID = ast.astID
       WHERE
          DATE_ADD(asgAssigned, INTERVAL 6 DAY) > NOW()
          OR astStatus IN('Not contacted', 'Follow-up')
 )
```